# Not able to catch error for .on() in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling

I am using below code to retrieve a value

```
try {
  discountFbRef.orderByChild('discode').equalTo(code).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log('snapshot val discode', snapshot.val().discode);

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {

        $scope.discountApplicable.id = data.val().id;


      });
    } else {
      console.log('It doesnt exist');
    }
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error occured during search', error);
}
```

When there is value equal to the search string it's working fine. But when I try to find a keyword that doesn't exist in "discode", It throws

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'discode' of null

For some reason even though I try to catch the error with `try-catch` and error function I am not able to catch it.
I need a way to handle the error and show message that search string doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the functions that are passed to the second and third parameters of `.on` are called a callback functions. That means they might get called *after* (asynchronously) the code you've posted has executed. You'll want to move your try-catch inside of the callback function.

```
function handleValueSuccess(snapshot) {
  try {
    console.log('snapshot val discode', snapshot.val().discode);

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        $scope.discountApplicable.id = data.val().id;
      });
    } else {
      console.log("It doesn't exist");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error occurred during search', error);
  }
}

function handleValueError(error) {
  console.log('error occurred on value', error);
}

discountFbRef
  .orderByChild('discode')
  .equalTo(code)
  .on("value", handleValueSuccess, handleValueError);
```

Comment: I moved them to the call back function it didn't catch errors. I'm not sure how would it work because there is a console.log() inside the call back it doesn't log anything.

May be I did something wrong could you show the code based on my code?

Comment: @Vamsiga I edited my answer to show what I was thinking. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Thanks it worked, I put try catch after the console.log() which is doing the snapshot.val().discode.